# Finding and replacing string if present in a JSONObj Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have a JSONObj which contains various elements. I want to perform a Regex (or some type of search) on the text data of this object and find various strings, and replace them with some other text, for example, I want to replace the string "content" with the string "http://www.example.com/content" :

```
description = jsonObj.channel.item[jsonCounter].description.replace(/\/content/g, "http://www.example.com/content");
```

This works perfectly, but I want to first check if a string is present, and then replace it, I tried :

```
if (holder.indexOf("about-us") !== -1) {
  description = jsonObj.channel.item[jsonCounter].description.replace(/\/about-us/g, "http://www.example.com/about-us");
} else {
  description = jsonObj.channel.item[jsonCounter].description.replace(/\/content/g, "http://www.example.com/content");
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: What is `holder` variable? And what didn't work? It would go if part or else part.

Comment: holder is my JSONObj converted to a string :var holder = jsonObj.toString();

Comment: Also, the if part of the statement never fires, even though it should.

Comment: Try: `if (holder.indexOf("about-us") > 0)` condition

Comment: Same result happens if I use that method, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: print `holder` variable and see what text you get.

Comment: I get "[object Object]"

Comment: Which explains why `indexOf` is failing since `holder` is not really a String.

Answer (score 0):

As you said **:**
holder is my JSONObj converted to a string :

```
 var holder = jsonObj.toString(); 

var holderJSON = {url:"http://www.example.com/about-us"}

alert(holderJSON.toString()); **// this returns [Object Object]**

if (holder.indexOf("about-us") !== -1) **// is never true.**
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: How should I convert the JSON to a string then? Or check the JSON for string like text?

Comment: var holderJSON = {url:"http://www.example.com/about-us"}

var url = holderJSON.url.toString()

alert(url !== -1) // returns true